ffmpeg change order of mkv streams and add additional encoding for one audio stream
Let's say I have an mkv file with 1 video and 4 audio streams.
One of the audio streams is encoded with dts codec. I want to add another version of this stream encoded in aac. I also want to keep all of the existing streams, and rearrange them in a different order in the output file.
Here's what is in the input file:
$ ffmpeg -i input.mkv
. . .
  Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(tv, bt709/unknown/unknown, progressive), 1920x800 [SAR 1:1 DAR 12:5], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn (default)
  Stream #0:1(rus): Audio: dts (dca) (DTS-ES), 48000 Hz, 6.1, fltp, 1536 kb/s (default)
  Stream #0:2(rus): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 448 kb/s
  Stream #0:3(eng): Audio: dts (dca) (DTS-ES), 48000 Hz, 6.1, fltp, 1536 kb/s
  Stream #0:4(eng): Audio: aac (HE-AAC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
. . .

I want the streams in the output file to be in this order:
0, acc encoded copy of 3, 3, 4, 1, 2.
I tried the following, but it gave me a file with 5 streams instead of 6.
ffmpeg \
  -i input.mkv \
  -map 0 \
  -c:0 copy \
  -c:3 aac \
  -vbr 3 \
  -c:3 copy \
  -c:4 copy \
  -c:1 copy \
  -c:2 copy \
  output.mkv

I found ffmpeg documentation here, but I still can't make a good mental model of how these arguments work.

try this mapping → ffmpeg -i in.mkv -map 0:0 -map 0:3 -map 0:3 -map 0:4 -map 0:1 -map 0:2 -c copy -c:1 aac out.mkv

Thank you. That worked.
